# Using indexOf in order to filt an array - ( Next.js app with typescript )

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have this array in my next.js app

arr1

```
[

  { 
    identifier: "60a17722225f2918c445fd19",
    name: "Ben Awad",
    _id: "60c94480b8d43c28d0a6eb73
  },
  
  {
    identifier: "60a455d11fa62a1510b408f8",
    name: "dev ed"
    _id: "60bf62cede309f1a30fe88ab"
  }

]
```

And i have this another big array

arr2

```
[

  {
    name: "Ben Awad",
    _id: "60a17722225f2918c445fd19
  },

  {
    name: "dev ed",
    _id: "60a455d11fa62a1510b408f8"
  },

  {
    name: "Katlyn",
    _id: "60a52500ce96f30c14fdaff9"
  },

  {
    name: "Mike",
    _id: "60c95deeb8d43c28d0a6eb74"
  },

  {
    name: "Kassandra",
    _id: "60c960ddb8d43c28d0a6eb7a"
  }

]
```

I want a new array who should have all users except for those who have similar ids with arr1

So this is the logic i did (*Notice that arr1 and arr2 will change constantly*)

**Me = arr1
AllUsers = arr2**

```
const LookFriends =
    Me &&
    AllUsers.filter(({ _id }) => {
      return Me.friends.indexOf(_id) === -1;
});

console.log(LookFriends);
```

The output should be Katlyn, Mike and Kassandra, but the console.log says...

```
[

  {
    name: "Ben Awad",
    _id: "60a17722225f2918c445fd19
  },

  {
    name: "dev ed",
    _id: "60a455d11fa62a1510b408f8"
  },

  {
    name: "Katlyn",
    _id: "60a52500ce96f30c14fdaff9"
  },

  {
    name: "Mike",
    _id: "60c95deeb8d43c28d0a6eb74"
  },

  {
    name: "Kassandra",
    _id: "60c960ddb8d43c28d0a6eb7a"
  }

]
```

I'm really having a hard time trying to filter an array based on another array, what can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use 'findIndex' in this case, then compare the _id field itself:

```
const LookFriends =
    Me &&
    AllUsers.filter(({ _id }) => {
      return Me.friends.findIndex(friend => friend._id === _id) === -1;
});
```

If you use "indexOf", it will compare the entire object to just that _id value.

Comment: It worked beatifully, i was mad and tired of trying to find a way out so i didn't tried this lmao !

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the identifiers from the first array and filter the second array if the element doesn't match any id in our object or our Set

```js
// with an object
const ids = {}

arr1.forEach(user => {
  ids[user.identifier] = true
})

const filtered = arr2.filter(user => !ids[user._id])

// or with a Set
const ids = new Set(arr1.map(user => user.identifier))

const filtered = arr2.filter(user => !ids.has(user._id))
```

Comment: I already found a solution, but thanks for your answer man !

Answer (score 1):

Please have a try with this code.

```
    Me &&
    AllUsers.filter(({ _id }) => {
      let bExist = false
      Me.friends.map( (friend) => {
        if ( friend._id === _id )
          bExist = true
      })
      return bExist
    });
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I would suggest using "reduce" instead of map. You can declare "bExist = friends.reduce", then pass it that way, so it is more declarative.

Comment: Somebody gave me the solution already, but, i tried this and it worked, thanks man !